# Angular how to get the non activated children routes

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, angular-router

In Angular you can always inject [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route) in your component to get a reference to the current activated route.

It has a property `children` which:

> Contains all the child routes **activated** under the current route.

I was wondering how can I get **all** the children routes (so also the non activated ones).

Answer (score 4):

You could use `route.routeConfig.children` to get the children defined in the router.