# Angular Router: How come Router ActivatedRoute.children is an array / has always only one child?

Tags: angular

I am building an app with angular router, that has a route (a), which has a child route, which itself has a child route and also one level deeper (z).

I thought I could access all `ActivatedRoutes` of the child routes in the `ActivatedRoute.children` array of route (a).
But it turned out when I navigate to level (z) each of the parent routes in have an `ActivatedRoute.children` with one entry, which is always the `ActivatedRoute` of one level deeper.

So how can I access `ActivatedRoute` of level (z) from route (a) without going `this.route.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0]` ?

Why is children an array at all? There is also a `firstChild` which implicates there can be more than 1.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'level/:id',
    component: ViewLevelComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: ':sequenceId',
            component: ViewSequenceComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'multi/:entryId',
                    component: ViewSequenceComponent,
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: 'single/:sequenceId',
                            component: ViewSequenceComponent,
                            children: [
                                {
                                    path: 'single/:sequenceId',
                                    component: ViewSequenceComponent,
                                },
                                {
                                    path: 'multi/:entryId',
                                    component: ViewSequenceComponent,
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            path: 'multi/:entryId',
                            component: ViewSequenceComponent,
                            children: [
                                {
                                    path: 'single/:sequenceId',
                                    component: ViewSequenceComponent,
                                },
                                {
                                    path: 'multi/:entryId',
                                    component: ViewSequenceComponent,
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    path: ':id',
                    component: ViewSequenceComponent,
                }
            ]
        },

    ]
}
```

];

Comment: can you share the code of your routes ?

Comment: just did, there you go

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46069944/angular-how-to-get-the-non-activated-children-routes?rq=1